# Powershell issue when creating new user then give them group and move to specific OU

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to PowerShell and still at entry-level. I'm running into an issue with my script and hope to seek some help here.
The objective I wanted to achieve is:
Create new users from .csv where their attribute values are filled
bases on their jobtitle: Add different groups, move the user to different OU

My script did work with user account creation and adding groups, but after I added the OU moving part, it failed. I'm attaching my script here and the error message, any advice would be really really helpful!!
Thank you very much in advance.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
      
 $ADUsers = Import-csv 'D:\OneDrive - testit\IT Dept\PowerShell\Scripts\Case_Study\New_Employee_Action\RA_Test3.csv'
    
 foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
 {
            
     $Lastname     = $User.EnglishLastName
     $Firstname     = $User.EnglishFirstName
     $department = $User.Department
     $Username     = $User.Account
     $Password     = $User.Password
     $email      = $User.Email
     $displayname= $User.Displayname
     $employeeid = $User.EmployeeID
     $employeenumber = $User.EmployeeNumber
     $OU         = "OU=Rachel test,OU=Users,OU=testit,DC=testit,DC=edu,DC=cn"
     $city       = $User.city
     $zipcode    = $User.Zipcode
     $jobtitle   = $User.JobTitle
     $company    = $User.Company
     $employeeType = $User.employeeType
    
     if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
     {
          Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exists in Active Directory."
     }
     else
     {
         New-ADUser `
             -SamAccountName $Username `
             -UserPrincipalName "$Username@testit.edu.cn" `
             -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
             -GivenName $Firstname `
             -Surname $Lastname `
             -Enabled $True `
             -DisplayName "$displayname" `
             -Path $OU `
             -EmployeeID $employeeid `
             -EmployeeNumber $employeenumber `
             -City $city `
             -PostalCode $zipcode `
             -Title $jobtitle `
             -Company $company `
             -Department $department `
             -EmailAddress $email `
             -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
             -OtherAttributes @{'employeeType'=$employeeType}
      }
    
    
         $RA_Groups = @("Chinese Staff","$testStaffUsers","testUsers","Research Assistants")
    
         $OU_RA = "OU=Research Assistant,OU=Academic,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU=testit,DC=testit,DC=edu,DC=cn"
    
    
         ForEach ($ADUser in $ADUsers) 
         {
          if($jobtitle -eq 'Research Fellow (RF)'){
                 foreach($RA_Group in $RA_Groups){
                 Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $RA_Group -Members $Username
                 }
             Move-ADObject -Identity $Username -TargetPath $OU_RA
             Write-Output "Moved Account $($Username) to $($OU_RA)"
             Write-Output "User $($Username) has been added to group $($RA_Groups)"
          }
         }
 }
```

```
 Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=testit,DC=edu,DC=cn'.
 At D:\OneDrive - testIT\IT Dept\PowerShell\Scripts\Case_Study\New_Employee_Action\New_Employee_test.ps1:88 char:17
 + ...              Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $RA_Group -Members $Username
 +                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
     
 Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test.RA' under: 'DC=testit,DC=edu,DC=cn'.
 At D:\OneDrive - testit\IT Dept\PowerShell\Scripts\Case_Study\New_Employee_Action\New_Employee_test.ps1:90 char:13
 +             Move-ADObject -Identity $Username -TargetPath $OU_RA
 +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test.RA:ADObject) [Move-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
     
 Moved Account test.RA to OU=Research Assistant,OU=Academic,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU=testit,DC=testit,DC=edu,DC=cn
 User test.RA has been added to group Chinese Staff  testUsers Research Assistants
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems here:

1. > Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test.RA'

`Move-ADObject` does not take the samaccountname as an input - the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/move-adobject?view=windowsserver2022-ps) indicates it wants either a distinguished name or a GUID. To solve this, once you have created the account, you can either `Get-ADUser` the username (to get the GUID / DN) or bodgy it up using your already known values from the script - I'd recommend using `Get-ADUser` for simplicity

```
$dn = Get-ADUser $username | Select-Object -expand DistinguishedName
Move-ADObject -Identity $dn -TargetPath $OU_RA
```

2. > Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: ''

You've defined the groups with names, but one is defined as a variable instead - it's likely here you're experiencing the error. You can see in the below that `$testStaffUsers` is a variable (identified by the $). Removing the $, or ensuring the variable is defined, would resolve the problem.

`$RA_Groups = @("Chinese Staff","$testStaffUsers","testUsers","Research Assistants")`

would become

`$RA_Groups = @("Chinese Staff","testStaffUsers","testUsers","Research Assistants")`